# Resource was blocked due to MIME type mismatch using pug and node

Tags: node.js, express, pug, mime-types

I'm trying to render a view with an id in the url:

```
router.get('/employee', authController.protect, viewsController.getOverviewEmployee);
router.get('/employee/:id', authController.protect, viewsController.getOneEmployee);
```

The /employee works fine, but when I get to the /employee/:id page the css and scripts won't load and the console shows me this error:

> The resource from
>   “http://127.0.0.1:3000/employee/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrapmin.css”
>   was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch
>   (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

this is my index.pug header:

```
doctype html
head
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  meta(name='description' content='')
  meta(name='author' content='Dashboard')
  meta(name='keyword' content='Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina')
  title Admin
  // Favicons
  link(href='img/favicon.png' rel='icon')
  link(href='img/apple-touch-icon.png' rel='apple-touch-icon')
  // Bootstrap core CSS
  link(href='lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet')
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='lib/bootstrap-fileupload/bootstrap-fileupload.css')
  // external css
  link(href='lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet')
  // Custom styles for this template
  link(href='dashcss/style.css' rel='stylesheet')
  link(href='dashcss/style-responsive.css' rel='stylesheet')
```

**getOneEmployee:**

```
exports.getOneEmployee = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const employee = await Employees.findById(req.params.id);

    if (!employee) {
      return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID', 404));
    }

    res.status(200).render('admin/employeeManager',{
      title: 'Employee',
      employee
    });
});
```

**and the employeeManager.pug**

```
extends index

block content
    section#container
        MAIN CONTENT
        // main content start
        section#main-content
            section.wrapper
                h3
                    i.fa.fa-angle-right
                    |  Editar Colaborador
                    .row.mt
                        .col-lg-12
                            h4
                                .form-panel
                                    .form
                                        form.cmxform.form-horizontal.style-form#commentForm(method='get' action)
                                            .form-group
                                                label.control-label.col-lg-2(for='cname') Nome*
                                                .col-lg-10
                                                    input.form-control#cname(name='name' minlength='2' type='text' required)
                                            .form-group
                                                label.control-label.col-lg-2(for='cphone') Telefone*
                                                .col-lg-10
                                                    input.form-control#cemail(type='cphone' name='phone' required)
                                            .form-group
                                                label.control-label.col-lg-2(for='cdescription') Descrição*
                                                .col-lg-10
                                                    input.form-control#curl(type='description' name='description' required)
                                            .form-group
                                                label.control-label.col-lg-2(for='ccomment') Your Comment (required)
                                                .col-lg-10
                                                    textarea.form-control#ccomment(name='comment' required)
                                            .form-group
                                                label.control-label.col-md-3 Image Upload
                                                .col-md-9
                                                    .fileupload.fileupload-new(data-provides='fileupload')
                                                        .fileupload-new.thumbnail(style='width: 200px; height: 150px;')
                                                            img(src='http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image', alt='')
                                                        .fileupload-preview.fileupload-exists.thumbnail(style='max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;')
                                                        div
                                                            span.btn.btn-theme02.btn-file
                                                                span.fileupload-new
                                                                    i.fa.fa-paperclip
                                                                    |  Select image
                                                                span.fileupload-exists
                                                                    i.fa.fa-undo
                                                                    |  Change
                                                                input.default(type='file')
                                                            a.btn.btn-theme04.fileupload-exists(href='', data-dismiss='fileupload')
                                                                i.fa.fa-trash-o
                                                                |  Remove
                                                    span.label.label-info NOTE!
                                                    span
                                                        | Attached image thumbnail is
                                                        | supported in Latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera,
                                                        | Safari and Internet Explorer 10 only
                                            .form-group
                                                .col-lg-offset-2.col-lg-10
                                                    button.btn.btn-theme(type='submit') Salvar
                                                    | 
                                                    button.btn.btn-theme04(type='button') Cancelar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are using relative url's in your attributes.

Replace this:

```
link(href='img/favicon.png' rel='icon')
```

With this:

```
link(href='/img/favicon.png' rel='icon')
```

To explain this further, when you are viewing `/employee` then the relative link at `img/123.jpg` is correctly resolved as `/img/123.jpg`.  However, as soon as you go to the url `/employee/joeblow` then the relative link is looking for `/employee/img/123.jpg`.  You'll be able to confirm this by opening Developer Tools in your browser then looking at the requests made in the Network tab.

Adding the slash at the front of all `img` elements will ensure that they look for the images in the correct folder, the one off the root (`/`).

The bootstrap mime-type error must be coming from one of the libraries that is loading correctly but not finding a dependency due to the issue described above.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to node.js. It solved the issue, I appreciate your attention.