# Broken image link in pug node js

Tags: pug

So images won't load for me in pug but everything else including css loads fine. I was getting a broken image link so I recreated the folder structure and used the same link (path) with normal html, css and the image worked so I don't know what the problem could be. I need help. [Screenshot of pug code and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSxnx.png)

Here's the route in the index.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
res.render('home')
```

});

I also set the view engine (These are working fine)

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource was blocked due to MIME type mismatch using pug and node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582878/resource-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-using-pug-and-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a route for the images too. Typically, you'll want to use [a static route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

The URL you give to the `src` attribute needs to point at that route (and starting the URL with `../` makes no sense given it is relative to `/`: There's no higher level to go "up" to there.